# Linking to a page and expanding a topic with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to link to a page which contains multiple support topics.
When the user clicks on the link while being on an external site, the topic should be expanded as soon as the user arrives on the support page.

Example:

I link to this page

```
http://www.nintendo.de/NOE/de_DE/support/nintendo_ds_lite_159_142.html
```

Topic I want to be opened on arrival

```
javascript:fadeNAppearDiv('box_3_9277');
```

(First topic in the FAQs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good idea, but I don't see the question... :-)

The way I saw on some sites, like deviantART, is to use the sharp anchor notation: myURL.com/foo/page.html#TopicToExpand

JS can analyze the current URL and get the anchor part, then do whatever you need to do to highlight/jump to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you are maintaining the target site (where the div will open) or not.  If you don't have access to the code for that page, then there isn't any way to invoke the javascript function on it.  If you can modify that page, you can do as @PhiLho suggests and modify the URL you are using to specify the DIV to open and have an onLoad handler that parses the URL and opens the appropriate DIV.